# ESXi 6.5 NFS41 always mounts as Read-Only

Tags: vmware-esxi, nfs, busybox

I'm trying to mount my NFS41 share from my Freenas box onto ESXi for backup purposes. However, it always mounts as read-only for some reason.

I have tried from the GUI as well as the CLI with no success, I specifically leave the --readonly flag off of the command

If I list my NFS41 shares I get:

```
[root@esxi:/vmfs/volumes] esxcli storage nfs41 list
Volume Name    Host(s)              Share                Accessible  Mounted  Read-Only  Security   isPE  Hardware Acceleration
-------------  -------------------  -------------------  ----------  -------  ---------  --------  -----  ---------------------
BackupStaging  [      snip       ]  /mnt/Backup_Staging        true     true       true  AUTH_SYS  false  Not Supported
```

The share is not set as readonly on my NAS.

Why is it mounting as read only, how can I get it to not mount this way?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that FreeNAS supports NFS v4, but not NFS v4.1

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the permissions on the NAS layer (root access, etc.). If possible you can change the sharing protocol from NFS to iSCSI which is faster and very powerful.